# Where does Cygwin install python packages?

Tags: python, windows, package, cygwin, spyder

I'm (desperately) trying to install [this](https://lesgourg.github.io/class_public/class.html) python package on my new Windows machine. 
I have downloaded and unzipped the tar.gz file, followed the [instructions](https://github.com/lesgourg/class_public/wiki/Python-wrapper) and everything looks good. Now, when I open Spyder and try to execute the program importing and using the `classy` module, though, I get the `ModuleNotFoundError`. How can I get Spyder (or Pycharm, or even executing the program from the command line) to acknowledge the installation of the package? 
Thank you very much

Comment: have you followed `https://github.com/lesgourg/class_public/wiki/Python-wrapper` ? And which of the cygwin python are you using ?

Comment: Yes. I have performed the instructions in the following order (note: the `class_public-2.9.4` folder is in no particular location, say it's on my desktop):
`make clean`->
`make class`->
`make`->
`cd python`->
`make class`->
`python setup.py install --user`->
and then, inside that Cygwin shell, the command `python -c 'from classy import Class'` works fine.
I have Python 3.8.6 and Cygwin 3.1.6

Comment: currently `python` is linked to `python2.7` (it will change in the near future). Have you tried with `python3` that is linked to `python3.6` https://cygwin.com/packages/x86/python2/python2-2.7.18-1 https://cygwin.com/packages/x86/python3/python3-3.6.8-1

Comment: Have you configured Spyder to use the Python in Cygwin?

Comment: I think that's really the problem, i.e. that Spyder is not using the Cygwin interpreter (although I don't know if that's even possible).

Comment: I tried repeating the process with the `python3` command instead of `python`, but it still doesn't work. How can I configure Spyder to use Python in Cygwin? Also, I tried running the program using classy directly from the Cygwin shell, but it won't recognize the other packages needed (like scipy) and `pip install scipy` will give the error `numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found`